# Auto import usings not working Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, intellisense, using-statement

I have the following selective problem with VS 2019 and IntelliSense.

When I start typing a class name which's namespace is not imported yet, IntelliSense suggests it in the Autocomplete column.
Once I press `tab` instead of completing the name and importing the using directives it autocompletes the whole path e.g.:

Typing '`UserView...`' -> `App.Web.Areas.Users.ViewModels.UserViewModel`

instead of importing -> `using App.Web.Areas.Users.ViewModels;` and completing the typing to just `UserViewModel`

But if I write the whole class name and then press `Ctrl + .`, then IntelliSense imports the using directive.

Do someone know which setting triggers this behaviour?

Comment: Hmm, what [is new](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/intellisense-completion-unimported-types-extension-methods?view=vs-2019) is that the name from an unused namespace shows up.  Click the "+" glyph at the bottom to turn the feature off.  Help > Send Feedback > Report a Bug to complain about this not working as documented.

Comment: I have this setting on, turning it off doesn't help. Thanks for the advice - I have reported the issue. Though I am doing something wrong

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually, I did not face the same issue on my PC.

My **Visual Studio 2019** version is `16.7.5` without any other third party vs extensions and I used `Newtonsoft.Json.dll`.

**Actually**, you should enable the option `Show items from unimported namespaces` and it will import `using Newtonsoft.Json;` automatically when you use TAB to complete the code.

**In my side**, I typed `json` and then use TAB to complete the class `JsonArrayAttribute`. And I did not face the issue as you described.

[image]

So I am confused that why this happened in your side.

Or you could try the following steps:

**1)** If your **VS2019** is not the latest version, please update it to the latest version and the new version will add the latest, most comprehensive features.

**2)** disable any third party vs installed extensions under **Extensions**-->**Manage Extensions** in case you have installed some extensions which caused that.

**3)** reset vs settings under **Tools**-->**Import and Export Settings**-->**Reset all settings**

**4)** after that, close VS, delete `.vs` hidden folder under your solution folder, `bin` and `obj` folder. Then, restart your project to test again.

**Besides**, if I misunderstood your issue, please point out and provide any detailed info to describe the issue to help us troubleshoot it quickly.

Comment: Thanks mate! Didn't believe this could fix the issue but updated to latest version and the issue is gone - easy rescue this time! Good job

Comment: where is this option? `Show items from unimported namespaces`

Comment: @JokeHuang it is in Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> IntelliSense. You can also use the search bar to get there